# Regex not matching empty string

Tags: java, regex

```
Pattern srcAttrPattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)(?<=src=\")[^\"]*(?<!\")");
Matcher srcMatcher=srcAttrPattern.matcher("src=\"\"");
System.out.println(srcMatcher.find());
```

This prints false. How do I interpret the above code ? Is there any modification needed to include src="" for the above code to serve purpose of empty as well as filled string. This statement is basically to match the src tag in `<img>` of html contents.

Comment: You can remove the last assertion, but doesn't guarantee a dbl quote at the end, change it to `(?=")`. But why go to all the trouble with a slow as paint dry assertions.. Use something more reasonable, `src="(.*?)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that to parse HTML, you'd better use some dedicated parser (e.g. [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)).

As for the current issue of matching a `src=""` string, the final negative lookbehind requires the character before the current location to be other than a quote. Since you are using a negated character class `[^"]*` (0+ characters other than `"`) you just do not need that lookbehind.

Remove `(?<!")` and you will match the empty string in `src=""` with the `"(?i)(?<=src=\")[^\"]*"`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zW5lU8/1)